# how to linearize if-then when having an operand?

Tags: linearization, logical-constraints

if $x_{i,j,p,s}$ and $y_{i,j,p,s}$ are binary and $z_i^s$ is integer; how to enforce:

$$
((x_{i,j,p,s}=1) \land (z_i^s \ge 5 )) \implies  y_{i,j,p,s}=1
$$

The value of $z$ in my problem could be 1 to maximum of 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First rewrite:
$$
(x_{i,j,p,s}=1 \land z_i^s \ge 5) \implies y_{i,j,p,s}=1 \\
\lnot (x_{i,j,p,s}=1 \land z_i^s \ge 5) \lor y_{i,j,p,s}=1 \\
\lnot (x_{i,j,p,s}=1) \lor \lnot (z_i^s \ge 5) \lor y_{i,j,p,s}=1 \\
x_{i,j,p,s}=0 \lor z_i^s \le 4 \lor y_{i,j,p,s}=1 \\
x_{i,j,p,s}=0 \lor y_{i,j,p,s}=1 \lor z_i^s \le 4 \\
(x_{i,j,p,s}=1 \land y_{i,j,p,s}=0) \implies z_i^s \le 4
$$
Now introduce binary (or just nonnegative) variable $w_{i,j,p,s}$ to represent the product $x_{i,j,p,s} (1-y_{i,j,p,s})$ and impose
\begin{align}
x_{i,j,p,s} + (1 - y_{i,j,p,s}) - 1 &\le w_{i,j,p,s} \tag1\label1 \\
z_i^s - 4 &\le (10-4)(1 - w_{i,j,p,s}) \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} enforces
$$(x_{i,j,p,s}=1 \land y_{i,j,p,s}=0) \implies w_{i,j,p,s} = 1,$$
and big-M constraint \eqref{2} enforces
$$w_{i,j,p,s} = 1 \implies z_i^s \le 4.$$

---

Alternatively, you can avoid introducing a new variable.  The convex hull turns out to be
\begin{align}
0 \le x &\le 1 \\
0 \le y &\le 1 \\
z &\ge 1 \\
6x - 6y + z &\le 10
\end{align}
The final constraint arises by replacing $w$ with $x-y$ in \eqref{2}.

Comment: Dear @RobPratt, as per the LHS is a logical AND, is it also possible to use the binary variable $x$ to represent $z\geq5$ simultaneously?

Comment: @A.Omidi Not sure what you mean, but I updated my answer with another formulation just now.

Comment: Dear @RobPratt, Thanks. Your intuition in the second form is interesting. What I meant was to link $z \geq 5$ and $x$ as the LHS is a ($\boldsymbol \land$), but it seems cutting off some of the feasible solutions.